# How to pass more than one value using anchor tag

Tags: asp.net

```
 <%--<a class="lbOn" href="viewlogin.aspx?pagename=articledisplayview.aspx">
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk_login" runat="server" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="12pt">
                ForeColor="DimGray"  Visible="False" >PostComments</asp:LinkButton></a>--%>
```

In `articledisplayview.aspx` page i assign slno value to label .i want to pass this label
with that same anchor tag to the viewlogin.aspx.i don't know how to pass more than one
value using anchor tag

thank's in advance

Answer (score 2):

isn't putting an **&** between query string parameters enough for you?

for example: **http://www.localhost.com/Webform2.aspx?name=Atilla&lastName=Ozgur**

check this one for details and info:

[Passing variables between pages using QueryString](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/QueryString.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
 href="viewlogin.aspx?pagename=articledisplayview.aspx&label=label1
```

you can add sevarel variables to query string using `&` .